# What is the better way to implement Video Player Controls in my IOS application?

Tags: ios, custom-controls, media-player, video-player

I'm using one third party library for playing videos. So on top of that library, I wanted to implement my own custom controls. So I implemented play, pause buttons, seek bar etc.

Now I want to add few more features like brightness control, and volume control, just like MX Player that we use in android devices. So can anyone suggest me which is the better way of implementing such features ?

Comment: AVKit provides the customisation to quite some extent but not really sure whether it supports brightness control you need to explore on your own :)

Comment: But here I'm using thrid party library to play the videos and since they are providing the videos URLs that library is mandatory for us to use. So on top of it I dont have to implement the AVKit right ?

Comment: If you have URL and want to play video you can do that with AVPlayer as well :) I have used it and found it very easy to manipulate :)

Comment: Yeah, but as I told you since they are providing its mandatory for us to use their Player, this is there in our agreement. My main concern should I go with Pan Gestures for Brightness and Volume control and how to handle the brightness and volume of my device while playing the videos.